# Simple jquery instructions attached on form is not executeing

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple js attached to a form, and I cannot see why it is not executing.

```
(function ($) {
    alert("test");
    $('#field-ai-event-date-unique-add-more-wrapper').hide();
    $('#field-ai-event-date-range-add-more-wrapper').hide();
})(jQuery);
```

The alert is popping up as expected, the jQuery instructions are not executed. They work fine in the console and hide the form elements as expected.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Well, could you please tell us what is the problem, that is what is happening? "Not executed" may mean many things, like control never reaches that point and even simple `alert` does not work (OK, that you excluded), there may be some error message in console (what message), they may get executed before `'#field-ai-event-date-unique-add-more-wrapper` is created, and so on... Last but not least, why aren't you using [behaviors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941426/drupal-behaviors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery 101**: If you want to manipulate an element in the DOM, the DOM needs to be ready first.

```
(function ($) {
  $(function() {
    $('#field-ai-event-date-unique-add-more-wrapper').hide();
    $('#field-ai-event-date-range-add-more-wrapper').hide();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

See [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

If you can convince yourself never to forget this small fact, life will be a lot easier :)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks Clive I knew it was most certainly a newbish omission on my part! Lesson learned, I appreciate bro ;)